# Will logger not follow the sequential execution

Tags: java, logging

I am using logger class from `java.util` package. I have observed that `Logger.log()` does not follow the sequential execution.

1. I had a log message in line 3.
2. I had a print message using `System.out.println` in the line 10. 
   Apparently, the log message appeared after the print message in line 10.

What may be the reason for this? Logger executing in a different thread?

Comment: Can you explain in detail? @immibis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logger statements in the program do not guaranteed to be in the same order while writing to the console or to a file (does not matter).

The reason why System.out.println() appears first even before the logger statement is explained below:

System.out.println() uses PrintWriter (does not use Buffering) so writes each character to console/file as and when called. Where as, Logging frameworks (java.util.Logger, Log4j, etc.) by default loggers (synchronous) use java.io.BufferedOutputStream. With BufferedOutputStream, the data will be waiting to reach Buffer limit/size and then once reached, it will will be written/flushed to the File or Console (rather than writing each character every time to file).

The below link explains how Asynchronous Loggers improve performance compared to Synchronous Loggers:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

> Random Access File Appenders (used by Async Loggers) are an alternative to Buffered File Appenders (used by Sync Loggers). Under the hood, these new Random Access File Appenders use a ByteBuffer +
>   RandomAccessFile instead of a BufferedOutputStream.

The below link explains how java.io.BufferedOutputStream works:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedoutputstream.html